# Can a self hosted windows service be public for other pcs in lan

Tags: windows, windows-services, signalr, self-hosting

i have followed this [example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/SignalR-self-hosted-in-6ff7e6c3/view/SourceCode#content) and works fine.
But i tried to open this user interface from other pc in same network and doesnt work.
I change "http://localhost:8080" to "http://*:8080" and from the pc that runs this service signalr hub is visible with my IPAddress, PC name or localhost, but with other device is not visible, i cannot find hub.
Also tried to close windows firewall and change the installer Account from User to Network but still doesnt work.

How can create a windows service that other device can have access to this. I want a SignalrServer hosted to service.